# How to create JTextField for the action of JComboBox by demand of user?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to dynamically create JTextField controls from the action of a JComboBox, where I need to get value from combo box.How to I create text fields dynamically by user demand?Like as user need 10 text can create 10 text fields by getting data from combo box.I am trying this code but it is not working.What is needed to change in this code?

```
 private void memberSelectionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
        int numberOfMember=Integer.valueOf((String)memberSelection.getSelectedItem());

     Object obj=evt.getSource();
     if(obj==memberSelection){

       UserUpdatePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2)); // matrixPanel is the dedicated JPanel
     for(int j=0;j<selectedMember;j++){

          JTextField textField = new JTextField();
          UserUpdatePanel.add(textField);    
}
       this.setContentPane(jPanel1);
       this.pack();
       this.setVisible(true);

     } 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. And explain your problem with an example scenario. It's not clear.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: BTW - what is the significance of the number varying? E.G. Might this be a shopping or task list? It is likely there are altogether better GUI approaches to achieving the goal. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

    private final JPanel  userUpdatePanel;
    private final JComboBox<Integer> memberSelection;

    public SwingTest()  {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        memberSelection = new JComboBox<>(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,19,26});
        memberSelection.addActionListener(e-> memberSelectionActionPerformed());
        add(memberSelection, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        userUpdatePanel = new JPanel();
        add(userUpdatePanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

     private void memberSelectionActionPerformed(){
         int numBerOfPanels = (int) memberSelection.getSelectedItem();
         userUpdatePanel.removeAll();
         userUpdatePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
         for(int i =0; i < numBerOfPanels; i++){
              userUpdatePanel.add(new JTextField());
         }
         pack();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> new SwingTest());
    }
}
```